# XML data into Java JTables

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have the following XML file

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Schedule> 
            <Lesson>
                    <Title>Maths</Title>
                    <Lecture Classroom="100">
                        <Day>Tuesday</Day>
                        <Time>12:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
                    <Lecture Classroom="101">
                        <Day>Thursday</Day>
                        <Time>11:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
            </Lesson>
            <Lesson>
                    <Title>Scientific Computing</Title>
                    <Lecture Classroom="103">
                        <Day>Monday</Day>
                        <Time>09:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
            </Lesson>
}
```

I want to parse it into a Java JFrame and I want to display the data in a JTable.I also want to sroll with a JCombo and select the data of a specific day as well as be able to add data in my xml through a JTextfield. ANY help appreciated!!!

[image: I give you the design of my frame:]

Comment: Try reading [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html) article first. You should parse given xml, it's possible in multiple ways. It's not a software house where you can order software and get it. Describe what you have tried, what problem exactly do you have.

Comment: I have parsed the xml successfully and I was able to print the data for example,but i don't know how to do it in the Jtable and Combobox.I want the data to be displayed in the Jtable and be able to filter them with the Combobox depending on the Day(e.g. Show only the Monday's lessons) @MaciejDobrowolski